# Treestore empty - is JSON valid?

Tags: json, extjs, tree, store

My code looks like this but there is there is no data in the store / tree.

Is the JSON store-valid? Do I need a `root` on top of the JSON?

What columns must be defined in the Tree panel?

**JSON:**

```
{
   "status" : {
      "status" : 0,
      "msg" : "Ok",
      "protocolversion" : "1.1.json"
   },
   "value" : {
      "name" : "Root",
      "path" : "\/",
      "leaf" : false,
      "children" : [
            {
               "name" : "subfolder1",
               "path" : "\/subfolder1",
               "leaf" : false,
               "children" : []
            },
            {
               "name" : "subfolder2",
               "path" : "\/subfolder2",
               "leaf" : false,
               "children" : []
            },
            {
               "name" : "report1",
               "path" : "\/report1",
               "leaf" : true,
               "children" : []
            }
         ]
   }
}
```

**My ExtJs Code:**

**Model:**

```
// Model for store
     var oModel = Ext.define('TreeModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
           { name: 'name',         type: 'string' },
           { name: 'path',         type: 'string' }
        ]
     });
```

**Store:**

```
     // Store with local proxy
     var oStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        model: oModel,
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
           type  : 'ajax',
           url   : './data/response.json'
        },
        reader: {
           type  : 'json',
           root  : 'value'
        }
     });
```

**TreePanel:**

```
     // View with TreePanel
     var oTreePanel = Ext.create( 'Ext.tree.Panel', {
        store       : oStore,
        useArrows   : true,
        displayField: 'text',
        rootVisible : true,
        multiSelect : true,
        border      : 0,
        columns     : [
           {
              xtype    : 'treecolumn',
              dataIndex: 'name',
              text     : 'Tree',
              flex     : 3
           },
           {
              dataIndex: 'path',
              text     : 'Path',
              flex     : 2
           }
        ]
     } );
```

Comment: Nearly all looks good to me, but the root and children property need to be the same, so I'd start by changing `value` in your json response to `children`, and define the root of your reader as `children`. Let me know the result of this.

Comment: Thanks! Changing `value` to `children` in my json solved it! 1. Can you please explain why it has to be `children`? 2. What role does the `root: 'value'` in my `TreeStore` play then? 3. Post an answer and Ill accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `value` to `children` in your json and in the root of your reader.

The way to think about is this: The reader's root tells the reader where record data starts. But because tree data is nested (a node can have children) ExtJS looks for another root within each node (then another root within this latter node, and so on recursively).

So if you called your reader's root 'children',it will find the subnodes within a node if it has `children` node.

You could equally call it 'subs', or 'whatever'; you just need to make sure the same thing is used throughout the hierarchy, include the root of the json data.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a tree panel i was able to get functional in MVC structure using 'data' as children:

**JSON:**

```
Ext.data.JsonP.callback4({
    "message": "", "data": [
      {
          "descr": "TEST REASON",
          "leaf": false,
          "data": [
            {
                "descr": "TEST REASON",
                "leaf": true,
                "data": null
            }
          ]
      },
      {
          "descr": "Another Type Code",
          "leaf": false,
          "data": []
      },
      {
          "descr": "Quite A Different One I Think",
          "leaf": false,
          "data": [
            {
                "descr": "A Child Of That",
                "leaf": true,
                "data": null
            }
          ]
      }
    ]
})
```

**MODEL:**

```
Ext.define('App.model.treePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'descr', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'leaf', type: 'auto' }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'yourURL',
        //extraParams: {
        //},
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'text/json;  charset=utf-8', 'Accepts': 'text/json' },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

**STORE:**

```
Ext.define('App.store.treePanels', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'App.model.treePanel'
});
```

**VIEW:**

```
Ext.define('App.view.treePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    xtype:'treePanel',
    title: 'My Items',
    store: 'treePanels',
    rootVisible: false,
    //hideHeaders:true,
    columns: [
        {
            xtype: 'treecolumn',
            dataIndex: 'descr',
            text: 'Current Types and Reasons',
            flex: .5
        }
    ],
    tbar:{
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Remove Item'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text:'Edit Item'
            }
            ]
    }
});
```

**Please note: `rootVisible:false` was required.**

Comment: Also note, my request is jsonp not ajax