# Can't show the json Data in Treepanel in extjs 4

Tags: json, extjs4.1, treepanel

I am working on showing JSON data in EXTJS 4 TreePanel. But my tree is not showing any data . Please let me know where I am wrong. Let me post my codes below:

View Part: it has got the treepanel

```
xtype: 'treepanel', 
title: 'Standard Geographies',
height: 250,
width: 310,
store: 'Data',  
border: 1,          
displayField: 'name',
useArrows: true,
rootVisible: true,
multiSelect: true,
preventHeader: true,                                            
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

columns: [{
    xtype: 'treecolumn',
text: 'Standard Geographies',
flex: 1,
sortable: false,
//renderer : change,
dataIndex: 'name'
}],
```

Model Part: Using json data

```
Ext.define('TA.model.TAModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name','typeId'],
//fields: ['abbr','type'],['name','typeId']


    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'data/StandardGeoTree.json',
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'geographyOptions' 
        },
    }   
 });
```

Store Part: I hope all is ok in the store part

```
Ext.define('TA.store.Data', {
//extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
//model: 'TA.model.TAModel',

extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
model: 'TA.model.TAModel', 
autoSync: true,
autoLoad: true,     
listeners: {
    load:function(){
        console.log('Schemes Data store loaded');
    }
},      
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    //url : 'data/StandardGeoTree.json',
    api: {
        //read: 'data/StandardGeo.json',
        read: 'data/StandardGeoTree.json',
        //update: 'data/updateTradeArea.json'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'root',
        successProperty: 'success',
        idProperty : 'typeId'
    }
},  
root : {
    text: 'Root',
    id: 'typeId',
    expanded : true,
    loaded : true,
    children: []
}
});
```

JSON

```
{
"success": true,
"root" : [
    {   
        "name": "001-USA", 
        "typeId" : "1",

        "children":[        
            {"name": "USA", "typeId" : "1", "leaf":"true"},
            {"name": "State", "typeId" : "2", "leaf":"true"},
            {"name": "DMA", "typeId" : "3", "leaf":"true"},
            {"name": "CSA", "typeId" : "4", "leaf":"true"},

            ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Why do you define a proxy in both the model and store? Because in the code you have provided, only the store proxy will be used.

Comment: Thats actually I got from somewhere as solution. Anyways I have removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the store configuration for tree component is actually doesn't need to be so complicated. for example simple store declaration below is enough:

```
var treestore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/StandardGeoTree.json'
    }
});
```

then in your tree configuration set `store: treestore` and `rootVisible: false`

finally, the store expect json respond in this format:

```
[{
    "text": "To Do", 
    "cls": "folder",
    "expanded": true,
    "children": [{
        "text": "Go jogging",
        "leaf": true
    },{
        "text": "Take a nap",
        "leaf": true
    },{
        "text": "Climb Everest",
        "leaf": true
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON, your root property has to be similar to your children. So it's either "root" or "children", but not both. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865288/treestore-empty-is-json-valid/11881664#11881664) for the full explanation.

So given you stick to:

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'root',
    successProperty: 'success',
    idProperty : 'typeId'
}
```

Your JSON should look like so:

```
{
"success": true,
"root" : [
    {   
        "name": "001-USA", 
        "typeId" : "1",

        "root":[        
            {"name": "USA", "typeId" : "1", "leaf":"true"},
            {"name": "State", "typeId" : "2", "leaf":"true"},
            {"name": "DMA", "typeId" : "3", "leaf":"true"},
            {"name": "CSA", "typeId" : "4", "leaf":"true"},

            ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Izhaki, but its still not showing any data.

Comment: Do you get the console log upon load? Also, could you comment the proxy on the model - just so we can zoom in on the issue.

Comment: Not getting any console log upon load. I have removed the proxy from model. In listener I have Added :



        afterrender: function(n) 
        {
         console.log('afterrender');
         console.log(n);
        },
        

Which is giving me the below log:


    afterrender
    
    Object { xtype="treepanel", title="Standard Geographies", height=250, more...}

Comment: OK, are you sure the `Data` store is in scope when you define the tree? Whether or not depends in whether you are binding the two via a controller as part of your application. Could you also try and load the store manually and see if you get the log upon load?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked as solution. So I had to write the below code part in my view which solved my problem. I am pasting the code part below:

```
    var treeStore = Ext.StoreManager.lookup('Data');
    treeStore.load();
```

But I want my store to be loaded automatically. Please let me know if you have any solution to automatically load the store.

Comment: I still think the last comment I have to my answer could be the solution. Could you please post your controller code?

Comment: My controller is working fine and I have binded all the stores and models in my controller. 
i crosschecked them. And surprisingly all my other jsons are getting loaded. Isn't it strange?